# Spring Boot 1.4.2.RELEASE with Eureka Server - Exception: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka

I am getting the following error while trying to run Spring Boot 1.4.2.RELEASE with Eureka server:

```
2016-11-20 16:25:59.306  INFO 14263 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@2177849e: startup date [Sun Nov 20 16:25:59 CET 2016]; root of context hierarchy
2016-11-20 16:25:59.581  INFO 14263 --- [           main] f.a.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor : JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
2016-11-20 16:25:59.606  INFO 14263 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'configurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration' of type [class org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$fc4b31a3] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.4.2.RELEASE)

2016-11-20 16:26:04.988  INFO 14263 --- [           main] i.v.p.s.EurekaServerApplication          : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2016-11-20 16:26:05.005  INFO 14263 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@3e14c16d: startup date [Sun Nov 20 16:26:05 CET 2016]; parent: org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@2177849e
2016-11-20 16:26:05.589  WARN 14263 --- [           main] o.s.c.a.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor  : Cannot enhance @Configuration bean definition 'refreshScope' since its singleton instance has been created too early. The typical cause is a non-static @Bean method with a BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor return type: Consider declaring such methods as 'static'.
2016-11-20 16:26:05.774  INFO 14263 --- [           main] o.s.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope     : BeanFactory id=05587591-c1ba-31c3-b56f-8b79a2e1951f
2016-11-20 16:26:05.787  INFO 14263 --- [           main] f.a.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor : JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
2016-11-20 16:26:05.857  INFO 14263 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration' of type [class org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$fc4b31a3] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2016-11-20 16:26:06.180  INFO 14263 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8761 (http)
2016-11-20 16:26:06.197  INFO 14263 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service Tomcat
2016-11-20 16:26:06.198  INFO 14263 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.6
2016-11-20 16:26:06.326  INFO 14263 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2016-11-20 16:26:06.327  INFO 14263 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1322 ms
2016-11-20 16:26:06.347 ERROR 14263 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.embedded.tomcat.TomcatStarter    : Error starting Tomcat context. Exception: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException. Message: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.server.EurekaServerConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'applicationInfoManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.netflix.appinfo.ApplicationInfoManager' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
2016-11-20 16:26:06.375  WARN 14263 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
2016-11-20 16:26:06.483 ERROR 14263 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field applicationInfoManager in org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.server.EurekaServerConfiguration required a bean of type 'com.netflix.appinfo.ApplicationInfoManager' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.netflix.appinfo.ApplicationInfoManager' in your configuration.
```

---

Here is the **pom file**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>my.test.springMicroservices</groupId>
    <artifactId>EurekaServer</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>EurekaServer</name>
    <description>Eureka discovery server example</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath />
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-eureka-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>Camden.SR2</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

---

The **application.yml**:

```
server:
  port: 8761
spring:
  application:
    name: eureka-server1
eureka:
  client:
    enabled: false
    fetch-registry: false
```

---

My **Spring boot application class**:

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.server.EnableEurekaServer;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEurekaServer
public class EurekaServerApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(EurekaServerApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

---

This is my environment:

- MacOS Sierra 10.12.1
- Spring Tool Suite - Version: 3.8.2.RELEASE (Build Id: 201610040743 - Platform: Eclipse Neon.1 (4.6.1))

---

Do I missed something?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `eureka.client.enabled: false` causes the issue it seems, you can remove it for a workaround.

Comment: Raised as an issue: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/1484

Comment: Removing `eureka.client.enabled: false` another error is raised: 
`Parameter 0 of method traceFilterRegistration in org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.server.EurekaServerConfiguration required a bean of type 'javax.servlet.Filter' that could not be found.
- Bean method 'resourceUrlEncodingFilter' in 'FreeMarkerAutoConfiguration.FreeMarkerWebConfiguration' not loaded because @ConditionalOnEnabledResourceChain did not find class org.webjars.WebJarAssetLocator
Action: Consider revisiting the conditions above or defining a bean of type 'javax.servlet.Filter' in your configuration.`

Comment: any solution for this problem? The solution above not works for me

Answer (score 5):

Remove `eureka.client.enabled=false` from the configuration. Then it will start the server

Comment: I am facing same issue. I dont have eureka.client.enabled in application.prop

Comment: i have same problem without eureka.client.enable

Answer (score 1):

In my case i have to use spring cloud version "Edgware.SR4" along with compatible parent pom version like 1.5.16.RELEASE to fix this.It seems to be some issue with cloud version and its associated dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, there was a **spring boot and spring cloud version mismatch**. Use https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud to check right version.

Answer (score 0):

instead of `eureka.client.enabled=false` you can write `eureka.client.register-with-eureka: false`

or remove `eureka.client.enabled=false` from configuration file.